# Finding the number of roots of the equation

Tags: calculus, transcendental-equations

The equation $x^{13}-e^{-x}+x-\sin{x}=0$ has

1. No real root
2. More than two real roots.
3. Exactly two real roots.
4. Exactly one real root.

I tried doing with the odd derivative  and check whether the derivative change sign or remain same(positive or negative) so i find $f^{(15)}(x)=e^{-x}+cos(x)$ now i am not able to determine how this will change the sign. Is there any other way to do the same problem thanks

Comment: Try drawing the graph of $x^{13}+x$ and $e^{-x}+\sin x$, you'll find one point of intersection, hence only one real root.

Comment: @Nikunj by 'drawing the graph' you mean by hands or some mathematical program, no I couldn't use it and if you mean by hand then $x^{13}+x$ is cubic like but much more steeper, but don't know how to draw $e^{-x}+sinx$

Comment: ok, think about this, for large x, $e^{-x}$->0 so the graph will predominantly be of sinx and for negative x, $e^{-x}$ will prevail, and as you say, $x^{13}+x$ will be like a cubic, only steeper and the graph can be made by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^{13}-e^{-x}+x-\sin(x)$.

Then, 
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}x^{13}-e^{-x}+x-\sin(x)\ge\lim_{x\to +\infty}x^{13}-e^{-x}+x-1=\infty$$

In the same way, $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$.

More over $f^\prime(x)=13x^{12}+e^{-x}+1-\cos(x)>0$. Thus, $f$ is strictly increasing. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, $f$ has only one root.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was going wrong doing unnecessary stuff  @sinbadh nice username.